# How to find which two tables are same in SQL Server database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I've a situation where I need to find tables with exact same columns. Its data doesn't matter.
Here is the scenario.

Table 1 `ANIMAL`:

```
SrNo | NAME  
  1  | Giraffe  
  2  | Lion  
  3  | Zebra
```

Table 2: `ANIMAL_TEMP`

```
SrNo | NAME  
  1  | DOG  
  2  | CAT
```

How to find ANIMAL_TEMP (SrNo, NAME) when I have table ANIMAL (SrNo, NAME) ?

Comment: Are you trying to match `SrNo` and `Name` ?

Comment: what's the criteria to tell that 2 tables are the same? you write 'with exct same columns' and then put an example of rows. which one is your choice? you want to match table structure or table content?

Comment: I need to match Columns only and not Data in it.. Matching Tables will be those Tables which will have same Columns as the One We are looking for..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try this one?

```
SELECT o.name table_name,
STUFF(
    (
        SELECT ', ' + c.name
        FROM sys.columns c 
        WHERE c.object_id = o.object_id
        ORDER BY c.name
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ),
    1,
    2,
    ''
) as columns
INTO #tmp
FROM sys.objects o 
where o.type = 'U'

select t1.table_name, t2.table_name
FROM #tmp t1
INNER JOIN #tmp t2 ON t1.columns = t2.columns AND t1.table_name <> t2.table_name
```

Comment: Thanks a lot zhongxiao37, It Worked :)